# Intellij idea missing one feature from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In eclipse, when debugging, let's say you have a method call with parameters, and then when you press step into, it'll evaluate parameters first and only then will go into function. But in eclipse there is a hotkey, so you put your mouse cursor on function name, press it, and debugger will stop inside that function, so it'll skip parameters evaluation (it will evaluate them, but won't stop there). Is there such function in intellij idea?
EDIT: there is a workaround for this, go inside method, put a breakpoint, then resume your application and it'll stop at that breakpoint. But is there a way without setting an additional breakpoing?

Answer (score 2):

If i well understanding,you can you the `Smart Step Into` debugging features([Smart Selective Step Into](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/compiler.html)). When you press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> a popup ask you into witch method you want to step into. 
You can select the method directly, avoiding the parameters evalutation.